# How to turn Ruby script into a web app

Tags: ruby

I currently have a script that listens for geolocated tweets that include given keywords and then plots them on a Google Fusion Tables map.

I am not quite sure how this transfers to a web app.  I would like an interface where users can type some keywords to search and then my app would open up a new instance of the Twitter streaming API listening for those keywords and plotting them on the map in real time.

I am having trouble wrapping my head around is where that background process 'lives'.  Any insights would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straight forward way would be to use [sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/), you could also consider converting your app to Ruby on Rails, however take into consideration the great deal of getting started overhead associated with a rails app.

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks! Googling Sinatra gave me this link -- [http://www.digitalhobbit.com/2009/11/08/building-a-twitter-filter-with-sinatra-redis-and-tweetstream/#comment-446954226]

Answer (score 0):

The web application development environment for ruby is Ruby On Rails.

This will also help you: [what is ruby on rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959912/what-is-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Ruby on Rails in a popular framework, but it is far from the only option, and not necessarily right for all apps/devs. Especially in @Josh's case I would probably recommend [sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com) if it's a simple script he's trying to put online.