# What is Ruby used for in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I really don't know how to ask the question that is actually in my head. Here goes.

I understand where HTML and CSS is used within websites.  I understand how you get them to the internet.  What I do not understand is what Ruby looks like to the end user. How do you get it out of the terminal/console?

Comment: An application, such as basecamp, is written in Ruby. You can see it's results by playing with the actual application itself. The application that is written in Ruby may not be directly apparent to a front-end user. Instead, Ruby in relation to Rails, will demonstrate a fluid process of direction in the environment of request and response. Ruby is a server side language, not a front end language you can directly see. Source code is rendered on the server, not the client. If this isn't clear, I can elaborate.

Comment: This article may help: [What Is Ruby on Rails](http://railsapps.github.io/what-is-ruby-rails.html).

Comment: This should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959912/what-is-ruby-on-rails?rq=1

Comment: On top of other things, Ruby (or any backend language) allows you to add dynamic content. Imagine writing only one HTML/css file that can be shown to different users with different names.

Comment: All right. I think this gets me going in the right direction.  Still not sure how you add this code to a website, but I am definitely better off.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like anything. There is nothing to see.
Ruby is only used on the server, and is never seen on the client (you).

Common tasks Ruby do on the server is to generate custom HTML pages which is then served to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is a server-side language. Which means when you need to do something that involves any other user or persistent data you make a request through one of the available protocols. Such as HTTP GET, POST, PUT, DELETE. Or stream protocols like WebSocket.

Server - as the name stands - serves the data which cannot be sourced any other way.

Comment: Just me, but I think saying Ruby is a server-side language is kind of misleading.

Comment: I know It's not fully true. But simple question deserves a simple answer. I don't want to make an answer mangled just because there are some exceptions of the rule.